# Extract div html from jquery object

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This is probably simple but I've never had to do it. I'm loading another page on the site and want to extract the html from a div with the id of terms_text.

So I am loading the data (it's there no problem), and am trying to filter it but am receiving undefined for my $html variable. Any ideas?

```
 function test () {
 $.get("/terms?" + new Date().getTime(), function(data){
     var $html = $(data).filter('#terms_text').html();
     alert($html);
});
}
```

Comment: You can used `Date.now()` instead of `new Date().getTime()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to use `$(data).find('#terms_text')` instead of `$(data).filter('#terms_text')`. Either that or there just is no element returned in `/terms...` with the id `terms_text`

Comment: This worked well! I used `var $html = $(data).find('#terms_text')` then to print it, `$html.html()`

Comment: That's exactly the same, I just meant use `find` instead of `filter`. You might want to nullcheck `$html` it before acting on it though.